# How to clear terminal/screen in scala

Tags: scala, console, deprecated, ansi-escape

I need to clear console screen in Scala

I've tried standard ANSI Clear screen which was suggested as *"Terminal control/Clear the screen"* by rosettacode.org [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Clear_the_screen#Scala)

```scala
object Cls extends App {print("\033[2J")}
```

I got following error:

```sh
Error:(8, 14) octal escape literals are unsupported: use \u001b instead
    println("\033[2J")
```

Comment: `print("\u001b[2J\u001b[;H")` or just `"\u001b[2J"`

Comment: even `print("\033[2J")` this also work

Comment: print("\033[2J") works in repl but it doesnt't work in Idea with sbt (at least in mu version 2.13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution for my question and I'll share it here for others, apparently from Scala 2.10 Octal litherals are deprecated [see here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5205).
In question above **"\033[2J"** didn't work since Octal litherals were deprecated, so just listen to compiler and replace it with **"\u001b[2J"** as shown below:

```scala
object Cls extends App {print("\u001b[2J")}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> worked for me to clear the screen in scala and spark terminal

Comment: The question seems to be asking to do it within a program

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Probably obvious, but note: this is a lowercase L, not a capital i. ctrl + l

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def clscr = {
   object Cls extends App {print("\u001b[2J")}
   Cls
}

clscr
```

Comment: This appears to just be **a repeat of the accepted answer**, but with less explanation, and more context. If this additional context helps address the core question, please offer an explanation of how and why. Without that, however, this doesn't appear to add much new value to the thread.