# Clearing the console in Scala

Tags: scala, console

I'm trying to clear the console during my program.

I basically want a command that clears the screen so that the result visible in the console after executing the following lines of code

```
println("hello world!")
println("double hello!")
//"CLEAR SCREEN" - COMMAND HERE
println("Goodbye")
```

would only be be:

```
Goodbye
```

I know this can be done in Python, but what about Scala?

Is there a built-in way to do this, and if not, is there any simple workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774983/clearing-the-screen-by-printing-a-character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear terminal/screen in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608263/how-to-clear-terminal-screen-in-scala)